# Add armor to the body without long weight paint

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

After character export from Unreal Engine, I have one merged mesh with vertex groups (terrible export, had to add 110 to Z coord of every static mesh). The body has the weights I need, but armor doesn't.
[image: Body has weights, armor doesn't]

Do I really have to paint all these 100500 vertex groups manually? If I don't use "limit selection to visible", I will paint something I wouldn't like to. [image: Paint not visible enabled]

If I do, I won't paint the inner part of the armor and there will be ugly tentacles. And if the body has "green" weight, I won't be able to paint armor correctly.

It would be great if it understood what's armor and assigned correct weights to it. Or at least can't I select the area and assign weight to it?

Blend file: https://files.fm/u/zaefgsjz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter edit mode, select one vertex of the armor, shift select a vertex of the other piece of the armor, Ctrl L to select all linked vertices, in the vertex group tab click assign with a weight of 1.0.

[image]

[image]

Another workflow: select a vertex from the body, Ctrl L to select all linked, H to hide the body, switch to weight paint mode and do all the paints you need (Face selection mode must be on, with all the vertices selected), Alt H to make the body reappear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the 1st way and had to subtract some dark strange copies of the plates (the inner parts?). This process is manual and cannot be done automatically, even if I have a separate armor plate object?

Comment: You can try Automatic Weights, but it's difficult it will match the body weights, and probably you will end up with ugly intersections. In such a complex character it's usual to do some manual weighting for a good deformation. Please accept the answer if it has been useful.