# Character rig not moving certain parts of mesh (Meta-Rig)

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, weight-painting

I have a mesh with a new Character Meta-Rig applied. All works well EXCEPT 1 part. The left shoulder pad.

When I move the right arm, that shoulder pad moves correctly. But when I move the LEFT shoulder arm, the shoulder pad doesn't doesn't move and just clips through the arm... I read other answers talking about weight painting but when I checked to see if the shoulder was highlighted correctly, it looked good to me... Any other suggestions?

Oh, and I'm sorta new to weight painting and rigging as a whole so... Go gentle on me.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a weight problem: having the pad with the correct weight relatively to the arm bone is not enough: you have to remove its weights relatively to others bones (chest, head, shoulders).

Check theese answers for more infos:
[How to make "Weight Paint" affect all vertices, even those with zero weight?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159180/how-to-make-weight-paint-affect-all-vertices-even-those-with-zero-weight/159214#159214)

[Add armor to the body without long weight paint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121542/add-armor-to-the-body-without-long-weight-paint/121545#121545)

Comment: I looked into it's weights but when I select that shoulder pad, the entire thing is red and nothing else... Doesn't that mean it's correct? Can I drop the .blend file for you to look at?

Comment: It's correct, but it's not enough, you have to check all the others veretx groups: your pad has some weight assigned to the wrong bone ALSO, and it shouldn't. If needed you can edit your question and add a link to your uploaded file.

Comment: Use this link for uploading: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Scratch that! I found that there were 2 "upper_arms"... One of them had that shoulder pad completely blue (Don't know why there would be 2 upper arms but whatever). Thank you for your help!